# Examples of inter process communication(IPC)

Tags: windows, linux, process, operating-system

I am wondering about actual examples or instances of inter process communication (IPC) which we encounter on a daily basis (which happen under the hood or otherwise) while using our laptop/desktop. I have always read about these theoretically from a textbook.

For example:

- Between a parent process and child processes: one example of this in Linux I know is when a  shell starts other processes and we can kill those processes using their process IDs.
- Between two unrelated (in hierarchy) but cooperating processes?

Comment: Drag-and-drop is accomplished via IPC.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing IPC on the two cases you mentioned is using **sockets**.

I recommend taking a look at [Beej's Guide to Unix Interprocess Communication](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/) for information and examples.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples of IPC we encounter on a daily basis:

- X applications communicate with the X
  server through network protocols.
- Pipes are a form of IPC: `grep foo file | sort`
- Servers like Apache spawn child processes to handle requests.
- many more I can't think of right now

And I am not even mentioning examples of IPC where the processes are on different computers.

Comment: Pipes in shell in Linux are one good example of IPC . Anything particular to Windows though?